# Вывод формы поиска в шаблоне yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Надо организовать поиск на сайте.
Форма должна располагаться на всех страницах сайта.
Сделал отдельный файл с формой, который подключаю в `layouts/main`.
Не могу понять как в форму правильно передать модель поиска.

Файл с формой (сократил код формы):

```
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
            'method' => 'get',
            'action' => ['/search-flights'],
        ]) ?>
        <div class="secondRow clearfix">

            <?= $form->field($model, 'city_from')->widget(Select2::className())->label(false) ?>
            <?= $form->field($model, 'date_from')->widget(DatePicker::className())->label(false) ?>
            <?= Html::input('submit',null,'Найти билеты', ['class' => 'peopleSubmit']) ?>

        </div>
<?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

Для поиска сделал отдельный контроллер с одним действием:

```
class SearchController extends Controller{
    public function actionSearchFlights()
    {
            $searchModel = new FlightsSearch();
            $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

            return $this->render('search-flight', [
                'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            ]);
    }
}
```

Поисковая модель:

```
class FlightsSearch extends Model
{
    public $city_from;
    public $date_from;

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return '{{%flights}}';
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['date_from','city_from'], 'required'],
            ['city_from', 'integer'],
            ['date_from', 'date', 'format' => 'php:d.m.Y' ],
        ];
    }

    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'city_from' => Yii::t('module', 'SEARCH_CITY_START'),
            'date_from' => Yii::t('module', 'SEARCH_DATE_START'),
        ];
    }

    public function search($params)
    {

        $query = Flights::find();
        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $this->load($params);
        if(!$this->validate()){
            /*$query->where('0=1');*/
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        $query->andFilterWhere(['>=', 'date_start', $this->date_from ? strtotime($this->date_from . ' 00:00:00') : null])
              ->andFilterWhere(['=', 'city_start_id', $this->city_from])
        return $dataProvider;

    }
}
```

Подключаю форму в шаблоне (я понимаю, что так передавать модель нельзя):

```
$this->render('includes/_header', ['model' => new FlightsSearch()]);
```

`Layout main` используется, кроме `SearchController`, ещё в трёх контроллерах.

Думал сделать виджет, где подключать форму и выполнять поиск по базе. Но, как я понял, после поисков информации по форумам, в виджете не рекомендуется напрямую обращаться к базе данных, можно только передать в виджет результат запроса к базе.
В документации сказано:

> При создании виджетов, следует придерживаться основных принципов
>   концепции MVC. В общем случае, основную логику следует располагать в
>   классе виджета, разделяя при этом код, отвечающий за разметку в
>   представления.

Так как сделать правильно? Чтобы передавалась поисковая модель в виджет и форма не очищалась после завершения поиска (в полях оставались введённые данные).

**Вопрос решён:**

В `SearchController` добавил переменную:

```
public $search
```

В `action`:

```
$this->search = $searchModel
```

Перед вызовом самой формы сделал проверку:

```
<?php

if(isset($this->context->search) && $this->context->search != null)
{
    $model = $this->context->search;
}
else{
    $model = new FlightsSearch();
}
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'firstRow',
    'method' => 'get',
    'action' => ['/search-flights'],
    'options' => ['class' => 'firstRowForm']
]) ?>
```

Теперь данные сохраняются в форме после отправки запроса. Оформлять форму в виде виджета не стал, так как форма будет на всех страницах одинаковая, с одними и теми же параметрами.

Answer (score 1):

Приведу свой пример реализации простого поиска. В шаблоне есть:

```html
<form action="<?=\yii\helpers\Url::to(['category/search'])?>" method="get" class="search-form" role="search">
  <input id="search-field" name="q" type="text" placeholder="Искать ..." class="hint" autocomplete="off" />
  <button id="search-submit" type="submit">Найти</button>
</form>
```

И в контроллере пишу:
`public function actionSearch() {
    $q = trim(Yii::$app->request->get('q'));
    if(!$q) return $this->render('search');
    $query = Book::find()->where(['like', 'name', $q])->orWhere(['like', 'keywords', $q]);
    $pages = new Pagination([
    'totalCount' => $query->count(),
    'pageSize' => 1,
    'forcePageParam' => false,
    'pageSizeParam' => false
    ]);
    $books = $query->orderBy('id DESC')
            ->offset($pages->offset)
            ->limit($pages->limit)
            ->all();
        return $this->render('search', compact('books','pages','q'));
    }`

Вывод: поиск реализован с помощью простого SQL-запроса с оператором LIKE.

Comment: В контроллере обращаться к базе не очень хорошая практика, как я понял из документации и общения с другими разработчиками на yii2